# Instance Declaration Haskell

Tags: haskell

My code is this:

```
type Code = [Inst]

data Inst = PUSH Int
          | PUSHV Name
          | POP Name
          | DO Op
          | JUMP Label
          | JUMPZ Label
          | LABEL Label
          deriving Show

doJump :: Inst -> Code -> Code
doJump l c = case (elemIndex l c) of
                 Just n -> drop (n+1) c
                 Nothing -> c
```

And GHC returns me this error, which has got me completely stumped...
What I'm trying to do is return the list from the point after a specific element occurs.

```
No instance for (Eq Inst) arising from a use of `elemIndex'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Eq Inst)
In the expression: (elemIndex l c)
In the expression:
  case (elemIndex l c) of {
    Just n -> drop (n + 1) c
    Nothing -> c }
In an equation for `doJump':
    doJump l c
      = case (elemIndex l c) of {
          Just n -> drop (n + 1) c
          Nothing -> c }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use tabs in Haskell. They don't work with significant indentation.

Comment: @rightfold There are arguments against using tabs in Haskell, but [that isn't one of them](http://dmwit.com/tabs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elemIndex` requires the elements of the list to be equality-comparable, so you need to add an instance for `Eq Inst`.

Use `deriving Eq` to have it generated automatically, for example:

```
data Inst = PUSH Int
          | PUSHV Name
          | POP Name
          | DO Op
          | JUMP Label
          | JUMPZ Label
          | LABEL Label
          deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Comment: Fantastic, that worked thanks. would it be possible to add an Instance of Eq Inst for just that function. Or must I do it for the whole data type?

Comment: @stell1315 Instances are always program-global in Haskell.

Comment: @stell1315 If you do not want to add `deriving Eq` to `Inst`, you could use `findIndex` instead of `elemIndex`.